# AngularJS ui-grid sorting in cellTemplate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I have a problem with the sort functionality in UI-GRID. 
Currently I receive my data in this way:

```
{
AccountID : 555,
Teacher: Somename,
SchoolName: 1
},

{
AccountID : 555,
Teacher: Somename,
SchoolName: 2
}
```

and etc.

I'm using a dictonary for my Schoolnames and I visualise them with:

```
if ( memberData.type == "dictionary" ) {
columnDef.cellTemplate = 
'<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">
{{ grid.appScope.GetDictionaryItemValue( "' + memberData.dictionaryID + '", COL_FIELD ) }}
</div>';
```

> The problem here is that the sorting function is sorting the schools
>   not by the received from the dictonary name, but according their ID's.

**What would be the best solution to this problem?**

I tried to use cellFilter instead of cellTemplate, but it also sort them by ID's.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried again with cellFilter and actually it works this way:

```
columnDef.cellFilter = 'dictionaryFilter:"' + this + '"';

columnDef.sortCellFiltered = true;
```

Currently that is my filter code manually:

```
 .filter( 'dictionaryFilter', function() {
        return function( input ) {


            if (input == 2) {
                input = 'High School';
            }
            if (input == 3) {
                input = 'Other School';
            }
            if (input == 16) {
                input = 'Another School';
            }

            return input;

        }
```

Is there a way to access the parent controller scope from this filter ? I do not want to hardcore the dictonary in the filter.